# How to start C Program on Server to run in background

Tags: linux, server, background-process

I have programmed a C program and tested it on my linux computer.

I have uploaded it to my server now and want it to run there the entire time as a background progress.

How is it possible to start a program which will continue to run after i close putty?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can leave the program running by adding a & to the call

So when you have been executing your code before like this in SSH:

```
./mycode
```

you would to it like:

```
./mycode &
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want running your program in background you must add the '&' character to command.

```
./program &
```

But the process will be associated to the current tty. If you close the current tty (in your case the SSH session) the SIGHUP signal is sent to all processes associated with the tty, causing them finish. You can see the associated tty to one process with *ps* command.

The *disown* command can be used to mark jobs so that a SIGHUP signal is not sent to them if the parent shell receives it. Before closing the current tty you can write:

```
disown %jobID
```

You can see the jobID enclosed in brackets when you run the program in background. Also you can see the jobID with *jobs* command.

You can run the command directly so that a SIGHUP signal is not sent to him. For this you can use *nohup* command.

```
nohup ./program &
```

Another way to avoid ending the program with the SIGHUP signal is to catch this signal in the program. In a C program you can do this with *signal* function that is in signal.h

But if you want run the program as a daemon or server, better write a Systemd service or a System V init script.

Answer (score 0):

In the middle of the executing your program, if you want to run your program in background.
First press `ctrl + z` then type `bg`.